# Django не создает некоторые таблицы

Tags: django, postgresql

Django не создает следующую модель

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Client(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_url=models.URLField(max_length=100)
```

Причем никакой ошибки не появляется (см. картинку)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А самое странное, что другие модели он создает, например:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Также ввожу команды `python manage.py makemigrations app` и `python manage.py migrate`

Модель успешно создается и соответствующая таблица для неё в базе данных **app_doctor**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также пробовал использовать отношение *OneToOneField* вместо *ForeignKey*, но результата это не дало. Хотя по [официальной документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) это отлично работает. Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Дайте угадаю, вы уже когда-то создавали миграции для Client, применяли и потом удаляли?

Comment: Да было такое дело. Я создал миграции, применил - они не сработали. Снова удалял и применял.

Comment: А когда вы создавали модель Doctor, какое название было у миграции?

Comment: Следующее **0002_doctor.py**. Когда создавал модель Client название было **0001_initial.py**

Comment: Ну тогда всё понятно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое бывает, если создать и применить миграции, потом удалить, не откатив, и создать заново с таким же именем. Django хранит информацию обо всех применённых миграциях в базе данных, и там уже записано, что миграция `0001_initial` у приложения `app` уже выполнялась, и выполнять её ещё раз типа не надо. А про миграцию `0002_doctor` такой записи не было, и поэтому она выполнилась. Раз уж вы не пользуетесь родным механизмом отката (через ту же команду `migrate`), нужно подчистить информацию о миграциях вручную.

Чтобы удалить информацию обо всех миграциях приложения (в вашем случае `имя приложения` это `app`):

```
delete from django_migrations where app = 'имя приложения'
```

Чтобы удалить одну конкретную миграцию (где `0001_initial` это её название):

```
delete from django_migrations where app = 'имя приложения' and name = '0001_initial'
```

После этого команда `migrate` должна заработать и применить свежесозданную миграцию.

Учтите, что это всё на ваш страх и риск, и если вы удаляете миграции вручную, не откатив их как положено (например, не удалив таблицу, которую миграция создавала), то в базе может получиться что попало и могут повылезать глюки. Внимательно следите за тем, что делаете.

Comment: and name = '0001_initial' Не обязательно. А иногда даже вредно :)

Answer (score 1):

Удалите таблицу db.sqlite3, сздайте суперюзера и миграции

Comment: Лучше показывать код не текстом, а только код/текст + код. Автор вопроса может наделать ошибок при своей реализации алгоритма. Такой подход является стандартом этого сайта.