# Django ProgrammingError at

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Доброго времени суток! Использую `Django 1.11`

Сделал вот такие модели:

```
class GeneraIssues(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.question)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'FAQ По общим вопросам'
        verbose_name_plural = 'FAQ По общим вопросам'

class RegisterAndEntry(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.question)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'FAQ Регистрация и вход'
        verbose_name_plural = 'FAQ Регистрация и вход'

class BalanceAndInvestments(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.question)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'FAQ Баланс и инвестиции'
        verbose_name_plural = 'FAQ Баланс и инвестиции'

class AffiliateProgram(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.question)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'FAQ Партнёрская программа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'FAQ Партнёрская программа'

class QuestionsFund(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.question)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'FAQ Вопросы о фонде'
        verbose_name_plural = 'FAQ Вопросы о фонде'
```

Вот `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(QuestionsFund)
admin.site.register(AffiliateProgram)
admin.site.register(BalanceAndInvestments)
admin.site.register(RegisterAndEntry)
admin.site.register(GeneraIssues)
```

При входе в админ панель и попытке добавить что-либо в эти категории получаю следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот подробный лог

[image: пр2]

Вот еще скрин миграций

[image: б]

Еще пользуясь возможностью, хотелось бы спросить, как можно сделать 1 FAQ модель, которя была бы связана ключем между этими модельками

Comment: makemigrations то делали после создания моделей?

Comment: @SkyFox да, делал
и migrate тоже

Comment: @SkyFox залил в вопрос еще скрин с миграциями

Comment: Дайте угадаю: вы удаляли файл со старой миграцией `0001_initial`, и вместо неё вы создали новую `0001_initial`, не почистив базу данных?

Comment: @andreymal совершенно верно)

Comment: Ну тогда вы сами всё сломали. Вы изменили миграцию с названием `0001_initial`, но никак не сообщили джанге о своих действиях — она продолжает считать, что миграция с таким названием выполнена и ничего делать не нужно. Теперь, когда всё сломано, остаётся два варианта действий: или починить базу вручную, или очистить её и создать всё заново. Подозреваю, с вашим уровнем знаний подойдёт только второй вариант.

Comment: Та же самая проблема с неприменяющимися миграциями уже описывалась здесь: [Django не создает некоторые таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705162/django-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: @andreymal что-то у меня не особо получается удалить как показано в примере.

не подскажете, как правильно это сделать? бд использую postgresql_psycopg2

Comment: Сделайте drop table всех существующих таблиц и не мучайтесь

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, помогло)